# Leak in Xtify iOS SDK 2.06

Tags: xtify

I am using the iOS SDK 2.06 and I noticed a leak when an alert is received.  The leak seems to start in XLappMgr at

```
-(void)appDisplayNotification:(NSDictionary *)pushMessage withAlert:(BOOL) alertFlag

lastPush=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:pushMessage];
```

where `lastPush` is never released

i have tried to release that but crashed the app...

I noticed that when I commented out the `XLMetricMgr` requests everything is works fine.

Is there a solution to this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2.0.6 is quite old (http://developer.xtify.com/display/sdk/iOS+SDK).  Upgrade the library to 2.26.